# Woocommerce Displaying the added product summary inside the cart icon hover

Tags: php, css, ajax, woocommerce

I am working with my own custom theme. I want to display the added summary product list inside the icon cart hover. how can I get the

- Thumbnail product picture
- Title
- Quantity
- Price

I also like to enable my "X" button so I can freely remove the unwanted added product on the list.
and also how I echo a Text once there is no item in the cart? [Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCXFw.png)

```html
<div class="cartbox">
<a class="cart-link" href="#">
<span class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></span>
<span class="aa-cart-notify">
<?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d', '%d', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> 
</span>
<span class="basketicon__total">
<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
</span>
</a>
<div class="cartbox-summary">
<ul>
<li>
<a class="cartbox-img" href="#"><img src="thumbnail-product.jpg" alt="img"></a>
<div class="cartbox-info">
<h4><a href="#">Product Title</a></h4>
<p>1 x ￥250</p>
</div>
<a class="remove-product" href="#"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
</li>                   
<li>
<span class="cartbox-total-title">
Total
</span>
<span class="cartbox-total-price">
<a class="cart-customlocation" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> – <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
</span>
</li>
</ul>
<a class="aa-cartbox-checkout aa-primary-btn" href="checkout.html">Checkout</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your code to this -->

```html
 <!-- cart box -->
                    <li class="cartbox">
                      <a class="cart-link" href="#">
                          <span class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></span>
                          <span class="cart-notify">
                          <?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d', '%d', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> 
                          </span>
                      </a>
                      <div class="cartbox-summary">
                        <ul>
                           <li>
                                <!-- Mini Cart Details -->
                                <?php
                                    defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
                                    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart' ); 
                                ?>

                                <?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) : ?>

                                  <ul class="woocommerce-mini-cart cart_list product_list_widget <?php echo esc_attr( $args['list_class'] ); ?>">
                                    <?php
                                    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart_contents' );

                                    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                                      $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                      $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                                      if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                                        $product_name      = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                        $thumbnail         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                        $product_price     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                        $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                        ?>

                      
                              <!-- Remove --> 
                              <li class="woocommerce-mini-cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_item_class', 'mini_cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                                <!-- X -->
                                <span class="x-remove">
                                 <?php
                                    echo apply_filters( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                      'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
                                      sprintf(
                                        '<a href="%s" class="remove remove_from_cart_button" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                                        esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                        esc_attr__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                        esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                        esc_attr( $cart_item_key ),
                                        esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                                      ),
                                      $cart_item_key
                                    );
                                    ?>
                                 </span>
                                <!-- / X -->
                                <div>
                                    <!-- Thumbnail -->
                                    <span class="cartbox-img"> <?php echo $thumbnail; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?> </span>
                                    <!-- / Thumbnail -->

                                    <span class="cartbox-info"> <?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_name ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?> </span>

                                    <!-- Quantity & Price -->
                                      <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                                    <!-- / Quantity & Price -->
                                
                                      <?php
                                    }
                                  }

                                  do_action( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_contents' );
                                  ?>
                                </div>
                              </li>
                            </li>



                                  <li>
                                    <span class="cartbox-total-title">
                                      小計
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="cartbox-total-price">
                                    <?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d アイテム', '%d アイテム', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
                                    </span>
                                  </li>
                                      
                               </ul>
                               <a class="cartbox-checkout primary-btn" href="checkout.html">Checkout</a>
                      
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                          <?php else : ?>

                            <p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message"><?php esc_html_e( 'No products in the cart.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

                          <?php endif; ?>

                          <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_mini_cart' ); ?>




                  <!-- / Mini Cart Details -->
                    </li>  
                  </ul>
               <!-- / cart box -->
```

Comment: wow this is full code. thank you so much!

Comment: @lei no problem ^^ enjoy coding!